# React Router no me funciona

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

Estoy realizando una página web informativa (sin nada de backend) y ya que tengo mucho tiempo para entregarla, decidí hacerla con React.js y con ese proyecto, ir aprendiendo de este framework. Estoy haciendo un curso y pues hasta el momento todo me ah ido bien. El problema es cuando intento hacer la parte de las rutas.

La página tiene 4 rutas: Inicio, Paisajismo, riego, Control de Plagas (es de una jardinería y cuidado de mascotas).

Con este código, intento hacer que me acceda al componente de paisajismo:

```
    import React from "react";

      //Importar react-router-dom.
      import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";

      //Importar componentes.
      import App from "./../App";
      import Paisajismo from "./paisajismo";

    const Router = () => (

    <BrowserRouter>

      <Switch>

        <Route excact path="/" component={App}/>
        <Route excact path="/paisajismo" component={Paisajismo}/>
        <Route excact path="/paisajismo:name" component={Paisajismo}/>

      </Switch>

    </BrowserRouter>
  )
  export default Router;
```

Sin embargo, al colocar esta ruta: `http://localhost:3000/paisajismo/`, me aparece el App (el archivo por defecto).

Intenté enviar parámetros a través de la url, pero tampoco me accede. Este es el componente paisajismo:

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";

//Importar componentes.
import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./footer";
import Titulos from "./titulos";
import Textos from "./textos";

class Paisajismo extends Component {

  render() {

    const {params} = this.props.match;

    return(

      <div>

        {/*<Header/>*/}

        <p>Hola, {params.name}.</p>

        {/*<Footer/>*/}

      </div>

    );

  }

}

export default Paisajismo;
```

Quisiera saber porqué no me funciona y cómo podría hacer para que me funcione. Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

NOTA: Tanto el Router, como el Paisajismo, están dentro de la carpeta Componentes.

Comment: tienes un typo es `exact` no `excact` y no creo que lo necesites en todas tus rutas, solo en el home, a menos que tengas varias rutas que tengan el url similar

Comment: Tal cual como dice Isaac, el parametro es "exact", el mismo te sirve para los nombres exactos, por ejemplo, si vos no le pones el exact a la ruta raiz "/" todo lo que contenga la diagonal va a pasar si o si por el primero, es por eso que no te esta funcionando